# Jenkins trigger build if shared library changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git, git-hooks

I have Jenkins `Pipeline` job define in my git repo as.

```
// File: deployment/jenkinsfiles/staging/Merge

@Library("my_shared_lib") _

import com.company.myteam.Constants

pipeline {
    agent { label "common" }

    triggers {
        pollSCM("H/2 * * * *")
    }

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: "50", artifactNumToKeepStr: "50"))
    }

    stages {
        stage ("Staging Merge") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def config = new Constants().repoconfig
                    ansiColor("xterm") {
                        myteam.pipelines.stagingMerge(config)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created jenkins job configuration as below.

[image: Jenkins Job Config]

Now, When I check the `Git Polling Log` its polling `shared-library` too.

```
Started on Feb 25, 2020 5:33:07 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 681f996e689bdeb9cfca2b167002b8ccd99590cb (origin/staging)
using credential github_username_with_token
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Service Account Username with token
 > git ls-remote -h https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/myrepo # timeout=10
Found 6 remote heads on https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/myrepo
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/staging is: 681f996e689bdeb9cfca2b167002b8ccd99590cb - already built by 53
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision e80628ec7c9dbc59decbc81a3b884dcaa963a8dc (refs/remotes/origin/master)
using credential github_username_with_token
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
 > git config remote.origin.url https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Github Service Account Username with token
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://myuser@github.company.com/myteam/jenkins-shared-libraries.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Polling for changes in
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git log --full-history --no-abbrev --format=raw -M -m --raw e80628ec7c9dbc59decbc81a3b884dcaa963a8dc..869b3a16e07d21a88d557f1857376bfed7717a6e # timeout=10
```

Whenever I change code in `jenkins-shared-library`, its start build for the job.

I tried `workaround` given in https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-39615?focusedCommentId=280729&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-280729, but no luck.

I changed my `pollSCM` to `githubPush`, but this also trigger when I change in `shared-library`.

I tried solution given in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41497 as `Ignore on push notifications` for `githubPush()` but still its triggering job.

Before moving to `pipeline`, I had `freestyle` project. Where there is section **Source Code Management**, where we can define the branch, and `githubPush()` was listening on that branch only.

[image: Source Code Management]

When we select project type as `pipeline` there is no **Source code management** section. May be due to that, its listening for all push events.

By `push` or `poll`, I want to restrict my jenkins job to trigger only when there is changes on `myrepo.git` only.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not using Webhooks to trigger the Jenkins Build?

Comment: I tried webhook too, but it send event when I update my shared library too

Comment: That is weird, The webhook should only trigger for the Repo that it was configured for.

Comment: yes, but that is happening if you have "Source Code Management" section, if you create pipeline, this section is not there. Did you tried on `pipeline` type of project ?

Comment: I'm using Webhooks in combination with Multibranch Pipelines. I've configured my git repo to trigger a webhook on every push to run just this project. Polling should then only happen on a push to the project repo.

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be solved by using legacy SCM option. Go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and select "Legacy SCM" option for share libs. this will resolve the issue completely, It worked for us.

[image]

Comment: I've tried the options from Ievgen's answer first, but this is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that you don't want changes in the shared library to trigger builds for your project/pipeline?

If so, you can do it per-pipeline by modifying the `@Library("my_shared_lib") _` statement to include `changelog=false` parameter, like so `@Library("my_shared_lib", changelog=false) _`.

You can also do that globally, for a specific library - uncheck the `Include @Library changes in job recent changes` checkbox (in global Jenkins configuration).

Comment: I tried that option it was not working for me.

Comment: Although this seems to be the correct solution as described in the docs, it didn't work for me either.